# is there a way to deconstruct exported variables into a new object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a better, less redundant way to write this.

```
const {
  consumer_secret,
  consumer_key,
  token,
  token_secret,
} = require('./config');

const keys = {
  consumer_key,
  consumer_secret,
  token,
  token_secret,
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @DominikMatis
I was trying to deconstruct variables from ./config to the variable keys directly. I have found the solution but this question was marked as a duplicate which didn't help solve the issue.
That's the solution I came up with

`const keys = ({ consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret,} = require('./config'));`